# iOS 8&9 iPad Share via Twitter using UIActivityViewController dialog closes with viewServiceDidTerminateWithError within 60 seconds

Tags: ios, twitter, ios8, dialog, ios9

When sharing via the UIActivityViewController using Twitter on some urls the Twitter share dialog will show and then hide if the user does not press post fast enough. This can be reproduced on iPad devices NOT in the Simulator. A quick example is easily shown using the Google Chrome app.

1. On an iPad Open Google Chrome
2. Open the URL http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/syria/11846382/Russia-is-building-military-base-in-Syria.html
3. Click on the share button
4. Select Twitter
5. The Twitter Dialog pops up, now wait 60 seconds. NOTICE that the Twitter Dialog disappears before the user can press post. Also the image on the right never populates.
6. An error is logged to the console:

   ```
   viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo {Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
   plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post interrupted
   plugin com.apple.share.Twitter.post invalidated
   ```

Repeat steps 2-5 with the URL http://apnews.myway.com/article/20150905/ml--syria-7872368035.html
6. NOTICE that after 60+ seconds the dialog is still up, and the image to the right has been resolved to a glimpse of the webpage. I think there is some problem on iPads where Twitter cannot resolve some URLs.

Repeat steps 2-5 on an iPhone 5 with original URL http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/syria/11846382/Russia-is-building-military-base-in-Syria.html
6. NOTICE that after 60+ seconds the dialog is still up, and the image to the right has been resolved to a glimpse of the webpage. On the iPad this same URL did not, I think that is part of the problem.

Code I am using to share in my app:

```
NSArray *myUrlArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSURL *myUrl =  [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/middleeast/syria/11846382/Russia-is-building-military-base-in-Syria.html"]];
myUrlArray = @[myUrl];
NSMutableArray *applicationActivities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:myUrlArray];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:myUrlArray applicationActivities:applicationActivities];

[controller setCompletionWithItemsHandler:
 ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
     NSLog(@"Completed: %@", completed ? @"YES" : @"NO");
     if(completed){
         // Do Something
     }
 }];

NSArray *excludedActivities = @[UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypePrint,
                                UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
controller.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;

controller.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem = //Add an anchor to a button bar item on your screen;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Has anyone else run into this issue when using the UIActivityViewController to share via Twitter, right now the only solution I can come up with is to make my own Twitter share activity and to use that instead of the built in Twitter one. I would really prefer to use the built in Twitter one though.

UPDATE: If I Pass in a UIImage as the second item in the array then this issue does not occur. It seems to be an issue with how Twitter generates an image from a passed in URL. My current plan is to just make the UIImage of the webview myself and pass that to the Twitter share button so that it does not rely on Apple/Twitter to generate the image.

Comment: Workaround: Convert URL To String and pass it as a NSString to UIActivityViewController, then the dialog does not close but the URL is shown to the user when typing the tweet. The characters in the Tweet are still the same though so it kinda lets the user more fully see the tweet. I'm sure some will complain but stability is better than the little thumbnail web icon and no url.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that this is happening in multiple apps strongly suggests that it isn't a problem in your app, and you need to let Apple know what's going on as soon as possible so that they can fix it.

But because I didn't want to leave you with such a short answer, I'll elaborate on it in the form of a song:

```
If the operating system's broken,
and there's someone you feel like chokin',
don't give the engineer a hug;
file a bug, file a bug, file a bug.

If the sharing service crashes,
and all your hopes, it dashes,
don't stomp your phone into the rug;
file a bug, file a bug, file a bug.

When you find a good workaround,
how you hate bugreporter's UI,
but if your Radar's really sound,
they'll fix it before the pigs fly!

So when you see such bad behavior,
and you really need a savior,
don't ask your question with a shrug;
file a bug, file a bug, file a bug!
File a bug, file a bug, file a buuuuuug!
[At bugreporter dot apple dot coooooom]
```

Thank you.  I'll be here all night.

Comment: It does not occur in Safari so I don't think its an Apple issue. I've let Twitter know since its an issue in TwitterKit which is what I believe they provide to Apple for 3rd party apps. Apple has it working correctly in Safari so I'm pretty sure its a Twitter issue and they have to provide an updated TwitterKit to Apple to fix it. Its likely an Apple dev knows the solution but has not informed Twitter about it.

Comment: Ah.  I was assuming TwitterKit was part of the Social framework, rather than a third-party framework.  My bad.

Comment: dgatwood your poem made my day! (after struggling with this bug in my app for a long time). Polar Bear I'll try your workaround. That's super helpful too.